# EntityManager throws OptimisticLockException when try to delete locked entity in same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa, optimistic-locking

Here is my code:

```
EntityManager em = JPAUtil.createEntityManager();

   try {

     EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

     try {

           //do some stuff here
           tx.begin();
           List es = em.createNamedQuery("getMyEntities", MyEntity.class).getResultList();

           for (MyEntity e : es) {
               em.lock(e, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
           }

           if (es.size() != 0) {

               em.remove(es.get(0));

           }

        tx.commit

     } finally {

        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }

     }

   } finally {

      em.close();

   }
```

When I'm executing that code I get :

...

```
..........
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Newer version [null] of entity [[MyEntity#63]] found in database
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapLockException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1324)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80)
    ... 23 more
```

Can anybody explain me why that?

Comment: Is this exception occurs constantly?

Comment: @Taky Yes. Everytime I try to delete a locked entity.

Comment: Could you please show getMyEntities named query?

Comment: @Taky: *SELECT u FROM MyEntity u where u.username=:username*. I omitted the `setParameter()` for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Does your MyEntity has @Version annotated field?

Comment: @Taky Yes, it does, otherwise it would throw another kind of error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have added the `@Version`-annotated column after you already had some entries in database, so that some null-values were created for the already-existing records. 
Now hibernate can't compare the versions.

I would try to set the version column to 1 for all null-versioned entities.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is thrown due to the fact that I try to delete a record that has a lock on it. Trying to delete this row, will set the version to `null`, but the version in the database still remains set to former number. It seems that hibernate core perceive a `null` value to be not reliable for this kind of operation.

If I have to do this kind of operation, I have to release the lock first on this entity.

Anyone with better knowledge on it has to clarify that issue.