# Unable to update entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have recently upgraded to `Hibernate 4.3.5`. Now, every time I update an entity I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.OptimisticLockException: Newer version [3] of entity [[com.careem.backend.domain.model.Booking#23153]] found in database
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityVerifyVersionProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EntityVerifyVersionProcess.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:389)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
```

I am using `springs 4.0.3`, `JPA and Hibernate`.

Comment: You should post your entity codes and other codes that raised the exception.

Comment: may be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455202/entitymanager-throws-optimisticlockexception-when-try-to-delete-locked-entity-in

Comment: Does your entity have a @Version field? It seems a problem of optimistic locking..maybe you're are trying to save an old version of your entity...

Answer (score 1):

Is a normal Exception .. maybe you using Optimistic lock feature with this attribute

```
@Version long version;`
```

see this [link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock)